# Rename Play-store App

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console

I am facing issue with app published in google play-store. I like to rename the app through google play console. but couldn't able to do it.

Is anyone know about it ?

Comment: Where did you try to rename it (exactly where inside play-store)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the name shown in your store listing or that you want to change the name that is shown on a device?

Comment: Did you manage to rename your app ?

Comment: App name inside app(that will be shown when you install app in device) can be modified by changing `app_name` inside `strings.xml`.In order to change app name (title name) inside play console ,edit title inside Strore Presence > Store Listing

Answer (score 4):

Try the following steps -

> open **Google play-console**.
>
> Select your app from the list of apps.
>
> Expand **Store Presence** > Now click on **store Listing**.
>
> Now rename **Title**.
>
> Finally click on **Submit Update**.